Newly added features are deleted when synchronizing on QField
I have a QField Project to keep track of forest restoration progress. I am using a polygon layer to outline the area worked and record important data about the days progress. When I save the feature by clicking the check mark at the top of the form, it saves it and I can see the new polygon as normal.
When I synchronize the project to QFieldCloud and return to the map, all the new polygon features I had just added only moments ago are gone.
It's not a symbology issue because they don't even show up in the features list.
What I had to do is visit the qfield.cloud from my laptop, download the most recent GPKG file version of that layer and replace it in my local folder.
Why aren't my projects syncing in their apps as expected? How might I fix this?

Is this a timestamp problem? Maybe something with my device?
